# Selecionar coluna numpy no for

Tags: python, numpy

Vou ser bem breve. Estou apenas querendo saber como colocar no for quando os valores da primeira coluna da matriz for menor que zero, os valores da segunda coluna sera um.

```
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

#Exercicio 1:

```
x = np.array([7.3,8.2,6.0,7.7,8.0,6.1,5.6,5.3,5.9,5.8,5.8,7.1,5.1,8.0,7.6,8.3,4.9,6.5])
y = np.array([7.5,6.2,5.7,4.4,4.7,5.8,5.0,6.0,6.5,5.8,4.5,5.1,5.5,6.0,5.8,5.8,5.7,7.5])
m = 100000
matrix = np.zeros((m,2))
matrix

for i in range(0,m):
    matrix[i,0] = np.mean(np.random.normal(x)) - np.mean(np.random.normal(y))
    
    if matrix[i,0]<0:
        matrix[0,i] = 1
    
dados = matrix[0: , :1]
sns.distplot(dados)
plt.title("Histograma da Distribuição Amostral da diferença das Médias")
plt.xlabel("Respostas")
plt.ylabel("Frequência")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para selecionar um elemento em uma matriz em formato de `numpy.array` escreve-se:

```
matrix[n_linha, n_coluna]
```

Sendo que `n_linha` é um `int` que representa o número da linha e `n_coluna` também é um `int` que representa o número da coluna.

**Obs:** em python, a contagem começa em **0**

**Ex:**

- `matrix[0,0]` é o elemento da primeira linha e da primeira coluna;
- `matrix[19,1]` é o elemento da 20° linha e da segunda coluna;

Logo, para selecionar em uma matriz o elemento da segunda coluna de uma linha *i*, escreve-se:

```
matriz[i,1]
```

ou também pode escrever como

```
matrix[i][1]
```

Então, para por o número 1 na segunda coluna sempre que o elemento da primeira coluna for menor que zero, escreve-se

```
for i in range(0,m):

    if matrix[i,0]<0:
        matrix[i,1] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia! Proponho a solução abaixo que elimina a necessidade do segundo loop `for` e do uso de `if`, pois apesar do uso de `for` funcionar, as funções de `numpy` para manipulação de matrizes e vetores normalmente são mais eficientes.

**Solução usando a função `np.where`:** Esta função itera a coluna desejada (0) e gera um índice das linhas onde a condição `matrix[:,0]<0` é atendida. O índice gerado está sendo usado para iterar cada linha correspondente à condição atendida e substituir o valor da coluna 1 pelo valor 1.

```
matrix[np.where(matrix[:,0]<0), 1] = 1
```

**Nova versão do seu código:**

```
x = np.array([7.3,8.2,6.0,7.7,8.0,6.1,5.6,5.3,5.9,5.8,5.8,7.1,5.1,8.0,7.6,8.3,4.9,6.5])
y = np.array([7.5,6.2,5.7,4.4,4.7,5.8,5.0,6.0,6.5,5.8,4.5,5.1,5.5,6.0,5.8,5.8,5.7,7.5])

m = 100000
matrix = np.zeros((m,2))
matrix

##SOLUÇÃO PROPOSTA - PARTE 1:
#Removi o segundo loop for e substitui pela linha comentada abaixo
for i in range(0,m):
    matrix[i,0] = np.mean(np.random.normal(x)) - np.mean(np.random.normal(y))

##SOLUÇÃO PROPOSTA - PARTE 2:
#Esta linha soluciona sua dúvida sem necessidade de for e if
matrix[np.where(matrix[:,0] < 0), 1] = 1

dados = matrix[0: , :1]
sns.distplot(dados)
plt.title("Histograma da Distribuição Amostral da diferença das Médias")
plt.xlabel("Respostas")
plt.ylabel("Frequência")
plt.show()
```